# How do I create control tables in DB2 UDB for setting up new replication

Tags: db2, controls, replication, udb

How do I create control tables in DB2 UDB for setting  up new replication

Answer (score 2):

The DB2 Replication Center has a GUI that will guide you through the process. You can use it to define every aspect of your replication scenario and generate the appropriate DDL scripts for your control tables. Here is a brief description: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.repl.intro.doc/topics/iiyrcintraidp.html